# debugging javascript without knowing exact breakpoint location

Tags: javascript, debugging

I would like to debug a javascript file named `somescript.js`, to have an idea what it is used for and when. This file has lots of functions. Manually setting breakpoints in each function would be very tedious.

Is there a method in any browser to either:

- Automatically set breakpoints at the beginning of every function in
  `somescript.js` file, or
- Tell the debugger to pause next time when it reaches any function in
  `somescript.js`

I know there is a button "Pause on exceptions" but it results in stopping inside libraries (jquery). After pressing "Step out" many times it finally reaches a function in `somescript.js` - one function. I need to know what the rest of the functions are doing, but don't know when they are called.

Comment: Have u used chrome developer tool?.

Comment: @Vinothbabu: Yes; he has.

Comment: Yes, I checked in Chrome, FF and Opera developer tools (but my knowledge of FF and Opera dev tools is limited)

Comment: @camcam Firebug in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any capability to set a breakpoint at the start of every function in a module.  I think what you will need to do is to study the code a bit and figure out what the main entry points are in the module or figure out which functions you most want to trace and understand and then set breakpoints in those specific functions.

One can often search for the installation of event handlers and figure out where various actions start, set breakpoints there and then step through them to learn how that particular action works.

Sometimes this is an iterative process too.  As you step through some things, you learn enough about other good places to set breakpoints.  Keep in mind that once you hit a breakpoint, you can also look at the call stack and see how you arrived there and perhaps set breakpoints further up the call chain for the next time you execute that function.  Debugging/learning like this is a bit of an art.  You find a place to start, trigger that breakpoint, learn some things that lead you to other breakpoints to set, learn some more and so on.